# how to find which function is getting called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, ace-editor

I am trying to edit the ace editor.

for e.g. when I type `>`, it automatically places a `</element>` after the `>` in the html mode.

I found out from looking at the JS that it is this function `var HtmlBehaviour = function () {...`

Now how do I find that te function for this beahvior?

-when we are typing a word, and run out of space on the current line, then whole word is moved to the next line. How do I find the function which the keyboard event for new character at end of line triggers using chrome debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an event listener breakpoint for the keyup event and trace through the code to find the function / behavior you are looking for.

[image: event listener breakpoints]